# Shell script in Automator is not working

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I've just figured out how to pass variables to a shell script in Automator thanks to [this post](http://web.archive.org/web/20131018214926/http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2010/05/07/passing-multiple-automator-variables-to-a-shell-script/) but now the script doesn't work, when in Terminal works well. I'm missing something? Tried with and without quotes. Btw the script is for converting audio to any format, in this case to m4r ringtones format.

```
afconvert [original-audio-file] [ringtone-file] -f m4af
```

Here is screenshot of automator workflow
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to tell the shell script where `afconvert` is installed. So, in the Terminal, type:

```
which afconvert
```

to find where it is. Then use the full path it displays inside your script, something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/afconvert "$1" "$2" -f m4af
echo $1
echo $2
```